# Is there a way to rotate OLEobjects?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that will append a page to the current document from a pre-formatted template.  This page inserts a picture based off user selection, which they have the standard excel supported images(i.e. .jpg, .png, .bmp) as well as PDF's(taken off an AutoCAD program that can only save as PDF/DWG/DXF file types.  The problem I'm having is that I cannot rotate landscape print formatted images the way that I can with the regular images.  I know that the problem is likely that not all OLEobjects can be rotated and the shaperange option probably does not allow for rotation.  That being said, is it possible to do this within VBA?

I have tried to use the OLEobject shaperange option, as well as inserting the PDF as a picture(which is not supported by MS-Office as far as I know).  I have also tried to select the OLEobject as a shape to no avail.

```
Set rng = crrntWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & tempRow)
'Allows for the insertion of PDF files into the workbook
Set oleobj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=txtFileName, link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
With oleobj
    'Inserts the picture into the correct cell
    oleobj.Top = rng.Top
    oleobj.Left = rng.Left
    'If the image is wider than it's height, image will be scaled down by it's width, otherwise it's height
    If oleobj.Width > oleobj.Height Then
        oleobj.IncrementRotation = 90
        oleobj.Width = 545
        oleobj.Left = (570 - oleobj.Width) / 2
        oleobj.Top = oleobj.Top + 2
        'Centers the image
    Else
        oleobj.Height = 625
        oleobj.Left = (550 - oleobj.Width) / 2
        oleobj.Top = oleobj.Top + 2
    End If
End With
```

The expected result is that the image will be rotated upon insertion, but I will get either a "runtime error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method" or a "runtime error -2147024809 the shape is locked and cannot be rotated if I use the shaperange approach"

Comment: Does this do anything? `oleobj.ShapeRange.Rotation=45`

Comment: Also, inside the `with` statement, you don't need to keep referencing `oleobject`, you can just put the rest of the property/method call

Comment: Unfortunately that produced an "runtime error -2147024809 the shape is locked" error.  As for the with, I was unaware that you only needed to reference the oleobj in the initial With statement, I'll make the appropriate changes to my code @Marcucciboy2

Comment: Was looking up something for you [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Rotating-OLE-objects.html). This might be the case with VBA too?

Comment: @JvdV Does this hold true for MS-Excel as well?  If so, is there another way to insert PDFs as images, I was under the impression that PDFs were only supported as being inserted as OLE Objects

Comment: Through VBA: After inserting your PDF as object (on a temp sheet), select it, copy it and PasteSpecial with Picture Format, then use shaperange rotation. (will probably costs some sharpness)

Comment: @EvR Would it be better to cut the object then copy it back in while using the shaperange rotation?  Also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial) is the resource I'm looking at when referencing the pastespecial.  It looks like it doesn't support PDF's, or would it be under the "Picture (Enhanced Metafile)" format?

Comment: When using PasteSpecial use .png or .jpg, (or make sure you have a picture instead  of a PDF in first place). My suggsetion is, when you only can use PDF, insert PDF, make copy of it and Paste it as a Picture, then you can use rotation.

Comment: @EvR I already have a section of code to handle and rotate all office supported img file types, but unfortunately need to also have a way to handle PDF's due to certain picture files being saved as PDF through another application.  Does the OLEObject copy as a PDF/JPG when you select it, or as an OLEObject?  What would the code for that be?  I'm a little bit out of my element in terms of handling PDF's with Excel.  Thank you for the help by the way!

Comment: Record a macro when selecting your added PDF, copy it and Pastespecial as png, and rotate it. When is suits your needs by hand, the recorded code could be optimized.

Comment: @EvR This seems to have worked actually, thank you very much for your help.  Luckily the resolution was not altered a lot!